# Substring from XML value to add additional column

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to get the substring of an XML value (`MacID`) where I just want the last 4 digits of the MacID and I want to add that as an additional column to the .csv I am exporting.  How would I go about getting the substring of 4 characters out of `MacID`?  I was hoping I could just use `MacID.Substring(8,4)` but that does not seem to work.  Any ideas?

Here is the bit of code I am referencing:

```bsh
$serverName = Get-Content C:\Temp\MPOS\MPOSServer.txt
$xml = Get-Content C:\Temp\MPOS\DeviceConfig.xml
$xmldata = [xml]$xml
$MDATcsv = $xmldata.DeviceConfig.ChildNodes |
           Select @{Name="ServerName"; Expression={ $serverName }}, RegisterID, MacID |
           Export-Csv -Path D:\Reports\MPOS\MDATInfo.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
$MDATcsv
```

and here is a bit of the XML file for reference:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeviceConfig>
    <Device RegisterID="1129" MacID="A4313596AEDD" />
    <Device RegisterID="1123" MacID="E425E7960663" />
    <Device RegisterID="1132" MacID="E425E7960666" />
    <Device RegisterID="1120" MacID="E425E796878A" />
    <Device RegisterID="1134" MacID="E425E7988992" />
    <Device RegisterID="1135" MacID="E425E798CBA6" />
    <Device RegisterID="1121" MacID="E425E79B3DD4" />
    <Device RegisterID="1127" MacID="E425E79BF845" />
    <Device RegisterID="1126" MacID="E425E79CD962" />
    <Device RegisterID="1112" MacID="E425E79DF316" />
</DeviceConfig>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Substring(8, 4)` should work, but you need a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) for adding another column/field with the shortened value, and you need to get the original property from the current object (`$_.MacID`):

```
... | Select-Object @{n="ServerName";e={$serverName}}, RegisterID, MacID,
                    @{n='Last';e={$_.MacID.Substring(8, 4)}} | Export-Csv ...
```

Other ways of extracting the last 4 characters are for example

```
$_.MacID.Substring($_.MacID.Length - 4)
```

or

```
-join $_.MacID[-4..-1]
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  Using the calculated property worked perfectly.  Thank you for your help.